# How to verify laravel passport api token in node / socket application?

Tags: node.js, api, jwt, token, laravel-passport

My question is about OAuth passport token in laravel application which is using sockets / node express sever as well.

I need to implement my authentication mechanizm on socket server. Something like this article: https://m.dotdev.co/authenticate-laravel-5-user-account-in-nodejs-socket-io-using-json-web-tokens-jwt-f74009d612f8.

Already Im building this mechanism with my own token. But I would prefer to use token generated for my Laravel API.

My point is how is this token builded ? Which fields of user are there and which keys are needed to check if token is valid on node server side? Is that even possible?

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: @RameezRami check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own solution was to create an endpoint in laravel for my node application.

The endpoint was actually responsible for veryfing my OAuth token from Passport. Something like that in simple example.

```
Route::get('/user', function(Request $request) {
    return Auth::user()->id;
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Just after connect to the socket server by client application, I must to send my token and userId and then after that make a call to the laravel endpoint to verify my token via userId. When my user and token was okey I give the permissions to listen the channel.

Comment: This will do the job but it doesn't seem like an elegant solution for a complex and large application iam working on. probably ill rewrite my laravel code to NodeJS.  since laravel and node are connected to same DB, is there a way I can verify the token using Laravel's tables in the node itself if i provide the APP_KEY or something?

Answer (score 0):

Do not create any proxy api back to laravel app.

This is my solution:

```sh
cat laravel_app/storage/oauth-public.key
```

Nodejs

```js
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...............................
The content from: laravel_app/storage/oauth-public.key
...............................
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`,
    });
  }
}
```

Of course, you can copy file and read from file instead of passing raw string.