# How can I validate a token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, passport.js

I have a laravel passport api, on my front end that is in react I created a private route, in this private route I called a checkAuth function, to know the user is authenticated, but for now I did this function passing only true or false to To test, as I am a beginner, when I tried to check if the token is true or not, I ended up crashing, because I do not know how to do or where to start, I would need a practical example, if someone can help me, thank you!

Even checking username and password, generating the token and storing it in local storage is ok. I just need to check if this token is true or unchanged.

Comment: You need to learn about oAuth, take a look to this 2 links, hope you will find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364110/how-to-verify-laravel-passport-api-token-in-node-socket-application      -     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55193862/logout-using-express-and-passport

Answer (score 0):

Just use auth:api middleware. This is just a simple routes file example.

```
Route::get('/validate-token', function () {
    return ['data' => 'Token is valid'];
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Also you might want to checkout the [Passport Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add Middleware on the route directyly as mentioned in previous answer
You can also use this condition

```
if (auth()->guard('api')->check()){
//do some thing
}
```